# Java looping structure (for loop)

Tags: java, loops

It's just a questions on a looping structure. I haven't seen one like this before, and was wondering if it was correct. And if so, can someone explain it to me?

```
for(count--;count>0; count--)
```

Comment: Test your code first please.

Comment: If that compiles (i am too lazy to try) it is simply a harder-to-read version of a "count down" loop that inits the initial count with the value of count-1.

Comment: as a whole the method is to order a stack. but i dont understand how that loop works. what is its initial value

Comment: thank you GhostCat. That makes alot more sense. And yes it did compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `count` has been initialized beforehand, this will loop one less time than the value of count, since the initializer (`count--`) decrements count before looping.

e.g.

```
int count = 2;
for(count--;count>0; count--) \\ Count is decremented to 1 then count is tested >0
{} \\ some code is executed then count is decremented by 1 and will fail the >0 test
\\ loop terminates
```

It's functional, if not exactly readable or 'good'

Comment: Thanks so much! makes alot more sense now